# How to set a variable to the most recent file in a different directory for a batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to set a variable to the most recent file within a separate directory from the rest of the batch file.

I've tried to set the variable location first, and then set it as the newest. I do not understand the second line of code:

```
set DSS_File_Location=N:/HYD/Precip_Grids/

for /f %%x in ('%DSS_File_Location% /od /a-d /b *.dss) do set NEWEST
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete. And you can check `for /?` and `set /?` to learn what these commands mean.

Comment: Any help on what I need to do to complete it?

Comment: Unclear what you want. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: All those options you are using within the `IN` clause belong to a command. You are not using that command within the `IN` clause.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with your code. Without going in to all of that, is this what you want? If so, compare it to your code to see the differences. It often helps to get the commands you are trying to use to work before working on the FOR loop.

```
set "DSS_File_Location=N:\HYD\Precip_Grids\"
for /f %%x in ('dir "%DSS_File_Location%*.dss" /od /a-d /b') do set "NEWEST=%%x"
```

Comment: @Gerhard Barnard. Thanks. You are absolutely correct about the quotes. I always do that myself. In this case I was minimizing the number of changes made to the OP's code... but that should have been done. I changed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
@echo off
set "DSS_File_Location=N:\HYD\Precip_Grids\"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /od "%DSS_File_Location%*.dss"') do set "latest=%%a"
echo %latest%
```

How it works. You set a variable called `DSS_File_Location` with a value of your path.

We then do a for loop on each file using the dir command, using bare format and using atribbutes `/a-d` meaning it will exclude directories in the dir command and then sorting them by date time as older first. `dir /b /a-d /od "%DSS_File_Location%*.dss`

Then lasly we use the token `%%a` and assign it to a variable named `latest` and we echo it.

To help you a bit further, learn about these commands on your PC. Open `cmd.exe` and type thr following:

```
for /?
set /?
dir /?
```

to get some help, only on the commands we used in this topic. You can see more commands by typing `help` in the cmd console, then simply running each command you find interesting with a `/?` switch.

Some tips, you will notice I added double quotes to the path, that will ensure no whitespace kreep in. Finally, even though it will work with `/` it is best to use a windows standard of backslashes in path `"N:\HYD\Precip_Grids\"`

Comment: That worked, thanks! I also really appreciate the explanations.

Comment: @CamBroussard it will work as long as your file names do not have spaces. If they do then this script will not work without a change to use the `FOR /F` option `delims`.

Comment: @Squashman. In this case it was not needed but yes, you're correct, scenarios change, sp updated ;)